# Updated to angularfire 0.8 resulted in a TypeError

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I followed along Thinksters tutorial about [firebase and angularjs](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/eqq96ECqkT/1-getting-your-project-set-up-with-yeoman)
It worked great but I wanted to use the new functionality of $asArray() which required an update of angularfire (0.8).

Somehow this results in different TypeError (TypeError: undefined is not a function). For instanc on:

```
var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));
query.$on('loaded', function () { //ERROR LINE
setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
```

and

```
findByUsername: function (username) {
    if (username) {
        return users.$child(username); //ERROR LINE
    }
}
```

I'm still able to sign in which means that i have connetction with Firebase. Does anybody have an idea of what went wrong or if I have to update anything more to get this working again?

## EDIT:

my setCurrentUser-method:

```
function setCurrentUser (username) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
 }
```

I've made an attempt to change my findByUsername-method:

```
findByUsername: function (username) {
        if (username) {
            return (users.$getRecord(username));
        }
    }
```

(relates to)

```
 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
 var users = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
```

Still don't know a good way to search through my firebase-array correctly without .$child(username). Do I need a loop?

Comment: Okay i've studied more about the update. '.$on' and '.$child' was removed for this update but why do I still get an error in my case 'query' is still "Undefined"?

Comment: Located the error to that :
"authUser.uid" returns 'undefined'

Comment: can you add the setCurrentUser method? It's difficult to tell how those two code samples work together. As it stands, it looks like "users" is undefined.

Comment: i'm sorry, the code is added above. I'm unsure about how i should search the array in a good way. Current solution returns null.

Comment: Are you calling it before the data loads? Try checking it again inside $loaded() promise.